# How to maintain index on incrementing counters in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

What is the best way to go around implementing counters and to be able to sort on them.

These counters are updated quite frequently and I do not want to reindex the entire document. The approaches I know of are:

1) To maintain the the counter values in some form of cache, query elastic search and sort in memory to return the results.

2) Maintain 2 indices in elastic search, 1 for the document and other for the counters. Issue 2 queries separately to elasticsearch and merge the results.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there updating the index too frequently is not an ideal use of elasticsearch.

Based on the information from this blog by elasticsearch, eventual consistency is the way to go.

https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-keeping-elasticsearch-in-sync

I will be updating my implementation based on the approach suggested in the blog.

Closing the question.